# Easy way to check ColdFusion range then select a value if outside of that range

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm new to ColdFusion, and I came across some legacy code that wasn't checking a GET parameter for a number. I'm trying to add some code similar to:

```
<cfparam name="URL.count" 
           default="5" 
           min="1" max="9999"
           type="range">
```

Such that nobody can just add arbitrary values like 50,000 or -1. I thought, that ColdFusion would use the specified default value if it was outside that range, but instead it appears to throw an exception and use the default only when nothing is specified.

I can try/catch the exception, but I was wondering, since I'm new to this, if there wasn't a better practice in ColdFusion for handling a situation like that. Perhaps there is another ColdFusion tag I don't know about—that sorta thing.

Answer (score 2):

CFPARAM is just used to set a default value for a variable if it has not already been defined. While it can be used to validate the data type of a variable, it can't perform conditional logic related to values. You have to do that manually.

```
<cfparam name="URL.count" type="numeric" default="5">
<cfif (url.count LT 1) OR (url.count GT 9999)>
    <cfthrow type="error" message="The current count (#url.count#) is outside of the allowed range.">
</cfif>
```

Comment: Bummer. I had thought about a try/catch block to catch values outside the range, but was hoping there was something like `outside-of-range-default=5` or something else nice like that.

Answer (score 1):

The practice for handling this in ColdFusion is the same as it is in any language - if/else.

```
 if (url.count <= 99999) {
 code for good count
 }
 else {
 code for bad count
 }
```

Now, since this is a url variable, it might be the case where you have control over that as well.  If it's coming from a form method="get", you can add some client side validation to augment, not replace the server side validation shown above.

Similarly, if it's coming from an anchor tag or cflocation tag that you generated, you can do something when generating that code to prevent the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Combine Min and Max, like so. I'd be more verbose but I think it only makes it confusing. (minimum between maximum between and...)

```
Min(Max(lower_boundary,currentnumber),upperBoundary)
```

As a function, more readable,

```
<cfscript>
  numeric function uForceRange(required numeric cNum, required numeric lNum, required numeric hNum) {
    return Min(Max(arguments.lNum,arguments.cNum),arguments.hNum);
  }
</cfscript>

<cfoutput><pre>Between 1 and 10:
7: #uForceRange(7,1,10)#
0: #uForceRange(0,1,10)#
42: #uForceRange(42,1,10)#
10.4: #uForceRange(10.4,1,10)#</pre></cfoutput>
```

This simple function is of course implemented just as easily in any language.